# How can I count the number of occurrences in a range of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I am looking to count the number of times a value is found in a range of cells between two dates. My range is not a table but has headers for "Date", "Time" and "Result". It stretches from `$G8:KT$992`. The image below shows how my range is laid out. I have tried the following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(contacts!G8:KT992,">="&1/1/2019,contacts!G8:KT992"<="&3/31/2019,contacts!G8:KT992,"="&Client Interested)
```

[image: Screen Shot Of Image]

I should get `2` if I was counting the number of occurrences of `Client Interested` between `01/01/2019 - 03/31/2019`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DATEVALUE` to evaluate dates correctly. Try:

```
=COUNTIFS(contacts!G8:KT992,">="&DATEVALUE("1/1/2019"),contacts!G8:KT992"<="&DATEVALUE("3/31/2019"),contacts!G8:KT992,"="&Client Interested)
```